# discord.py Распознать речь в голосовом канале

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Как подключиться к голосовому каналу и распознать речь одного из участников (получить строку)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент, к сожалению, нету возможности реализовать это каким-то адекватным методом.